# UIBarButtonItem Not Displaying in Navigation

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I used storyboard to create `UIBarbuttobitem` and pass some functions to it, but it's not working. I then did it programmatically but when I run it, it doesn't show the `Barbuttonitem` in the navigation controller.

Below is my code:

```
   UIBarButtonItem *refreshLocation =[[uibarbuttonitem alloc] initwithbarbuttonitem:uibarbuttonsystemItempagecurl target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
   [refreshlocation setImage:[uiimage imagenamed:@""]];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refresh;

   -(void)refresh:(id) sender {

   }
```

Comment: Please make sure, you got a UINavigationController set: NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController); for example, should not be (null).

Comment: I have a UINavigation set cause I checked and I have a UIButton attached to the titleView

Comment: Ok, as the button has no title and also no image set (empty image), it will be invisible. You did use "setImage:" with an Image, which actually exists? Furthermore, you could also use:     UIBarButtonItem *refreshLocation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as the button has no title and also no image set (empty image), it will be invisible.

You did use "setImage:" with an Image, which actually exists?
Furthermore, you could also use:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshLocation = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
```